# How to get right dependencie versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, build.gradle

I was trying to implement cloud firestore database into my app. Firestore is still in beta and I had no idea what version would it need so I just copyed the same version as the firebase-core had. After syncing I got loads of erros and I played with the versions until there was only one error message left. It suggested that I should change my com.google.gms:google-services version to the latest one. So that's what I did. Now I'm getting this error message:

```
Error:In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the   library will be unknown.
Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.2.0.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@16.1.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@19.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database@2.1.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@17.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@16.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.9
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@16.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database@17.0.0

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.
```

So now I am thinking that my dependencie versions are all over the place. I never really understood much about them and I would need some help with sorting them out. Here are my gradle files

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.aapotti.thecarapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Build -> edit libraries and dependencies. A new window will open. You will find the "+" symbol on the top right corner click on it and type keyword in the search bar and hit enter. And you are done just choose your desired library dependency from search result. Let me know if this is helpful.